# Using REST when colon appears in column name

Tags: list, rest, api

I have a columns named 'Image:Thumbnail' and 'Image:Picture'. I am trying to refer to these columns using the REST API.

I have tried using '_x003a_' (as in 'Image_x003a_Thumbnail') instead of the colon but the request comes back as null.

Apart from renaming the column is there another way to get the field data using the REST API??

Comment: Jason, You mean you had to rename the columns in your xml like 'Image_x003a_Thumbnail.Url'? I am having a similar issue with the column name having colon in it ('OSI:PlatformName'). Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yep, just replace ":" with "_x003a_" with underscores, also the answer below explains that the display name may be different to the internal name, use the internal name - see the link in the answer for internal names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The internal name for columns replaces colons with `_x003a_` just like you suspected. So a column named `Image:Thumbnail` should be `Image_x003a_Thumbnail` as you suggested.

I'm guessing that the display name was changed later and the internal name is different. You can find the name of all your internal fields via the REST API and this will probably shed some light on this. Here's a sample URL for pulling this information:

```
https://mysharepointsite.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List')/fields
```

Look for the result where Title = Image:Thumbnail and then look at the InternalName property.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I did have the right idea, but i needed to add .Url or .Description (case sensitive) to get my required info.